# State Params work incorrectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state

move to another page with paramentrs by

```
$scope.singlepage = function($url) {
             $url;
             console.log($url);
            $state.go('app.paymentinfo', { "userId": $url});
            };
```

There add state and State param

```
angular.module('app.feedback').controller('singleCourseFeedbackCtrl', ['feedbackApiSet','$scope','$state','$stateParams','httpService','fileReader',
    function(feedbackApiSet,$scope, $stateParams, $state,httpService,fileReader){
```

but in my code  $stateParams, $state mixed up

When I get right code like this:

My code is not working. get error in console cannot read property '' of undefined state param

```
angular.module('app.feedback').controller('singleCourseFeedbackCtrl', ['feedbackApiSet','$scope','$stateParams','$state','httpService','fileReader',
    function(feedbackApiSet,$scope, $stateParams, $state,httpService,fileReader){
```

How I get params `$scope.showprofile = $stateParams.params.userId;`

my state in module:

```
.state ('app.singleCourseFeedback', {
                            url : '/singleCourseFeedback/:userId',
            templateUrl : 'modules/feedback/views/singleCourseFeedback.html',
            controller : 'singleCourseFeedbackCtrl'
                        })
```

Why all works, if they write incorrectly?

Comment: `$state.params.userId` or `$stateParams.userId` but not `$stateParams.params.userId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `$stateParams.userId;` without the params.